# Select comparação data atual com data exatos 1 mês atrás

Tags: sql, postgresql

Fiz esse select que me retorna a quantidade de registros nas últimas 24h

```
select count(*) from registros 
where registry_date >= NOW() - interval '24 hours'
```

Preciso de um select que compare o valor que é retornado nessa primeira query com o valor da mesma data no mês anterior.

Exemplo: Hoje (10/10/2018) foram 90 registros. Preciso comparar esses 90 registros com a quantidade de registros do dia 10/09/2018

Comment: CURRENT_DATE - interval '1 month' fornece a data do mês anterior.

Comment: @Programmer dá uma olhada na minha resposta..

Comment: Você precisa retornar os dois valores na mesma query ou apenas um? Ex: retornaria duas linhas uma com a data 10/10/2018 e 90 registros e a outra 10/09/2018 e a quantidade de registros?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você precisa dos totais por dia, tipo total dia 10/10/2018, total dia 09/10/2018; ou seja, a comparação deve ser feita pelo dia ao invés de -24h (desta forma você pega parte do total do dia 10 e parte do dia 09).

Tente assim:

```
-- total de hoje
select count(*) from registros 
where to_char(registry_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = to_char(NOW(), 'DD-MON-YYYY')

-- total um mês atrás
select count(*) from registros 
where to_char(registry_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') = to_char((NOW() - interval '1 month'), 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom se entendi corretamente você precisa dos dois valores na mesma query, acredito que ficaria algo nesse estilo, caso o seu campo 'registry date' esteja no formato data hora ira precisar agrupar por date.

```
select count(*) from registros 
where
registry_date >= NOW() - interval '24 hours'
or
registry_date = NOW() - interval '1 month'
```